# Netbeans debugger not working (GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 1)

Tags: debugging, netbeans, gdb

Everytime I try to debug my project with netbeans it doesn't let me do so. It gives the following error:-

"GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 1"

And when I choose 'ok' it just stops everything. My project runs without any errors when I try to do so in netbeans. I want to step into my code and not being able to do so. Can somebody help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you run gdb on your system (from command line). If not, what's the error message?

Comment: Yes I can run gdb from command line.

Like I said when I try to debug my project a window pops up with this warning "GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 1"...And the only option I have is to press "ok", when I do that everything stops. Surprisingly when I run the program, it works fine. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Different from your case, it returns 127 to me and Netbeans looks hanging up. I have Netbeans 7.4.1 and installed GDB 7.6.1 to replace the old version that came along with Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  I cleared my old debug breakpoints and this clear up the issues.  I think the old breakpoints were pointing to dead code.

Comment: I just had this very same problem. Cleared out breakpoints manually, but was also able to delete by Delete All (phantom?). This however still did not help, nor did reboots, or Netbeans restarts. I updated my system and things work again! I probably had patches pending (Ubuntu desktop).

Answer (score 0):

**Gdb Init File** was the problem for me.

Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize > Debug

It was pointing to `~/.gdbinit`, I cleared that field, and it worked.

Must be something crazy I had in my `.gdbinit`, even though it works fine with raw `gdb`.

Netbeans 8.2.

Comment: This actually fixed it for me.  I didn't even have a .gdbinit file in the location indicated, but clearing the field fixed the problem.  Perhaps if I had created an empty .gdbinit.